# How can I trigger a fusion charts drill down event from the legendItemRollover to display linked chart

Tags: fusioncharts

How can I configure my `legendItemRollover` event in Javascript implementation of fusion charts to display a linked chart like `newchart-xml-chart2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now there is no support for drill down feature using `legendItemRollOver` event callback.

As a workaround, you can implement drill down feature by rendering the charts on `legendItemRollOver`.

Please refer to this fiddle for the implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/k27mw4f1/

```
"legendItemRollOver": function(evtObj) {
      if (evtObj.data.datasetIndex === 0) {
        new FusionCharts(
          child1Chart
        ).render();
      }
      if (evtObj.data.datasetIndex === 1) {
        new FusionCharts(
          child2Chart
        ).render();
      }
}
```

Please implement it at your end and let me know if you have any questions.